# CSS: Why does converting a hex color to hsl and then back to hex lead to a different value

Tags: css, rgb, hsl

Strange thing that I discovered. When converting `#579f2f` to hsl, I arrive at `hsl(99, 54%, 40%);`. When converting this back to hex I get `#559d2f`. I used various online tools to test this.

I guess the reason is that hsl describes the colors as hue (0-360), saturation (0-100%) and lightness (0-100%) and hex is just RGB (0-255,0-255,0-255) written as three hexadecimal numbers, so the color space hsl describes (or the amount of colors you can possibly express) is different.

```
RGB: 255^3 = 16,581,375 colors
HSL: 360*100*100 = 3,600,000 colors
```

Am I right in this assumption or is there a different reason?

Comment: The actual HSL for #579f2f would be `hsl(98.6, 54.4%, 40.4%)` so I'd say it's because of the rounding. Try it here: https://convertacolor.com/

Comment: This is because of rounding the hsl values to int's. And, yes you can cpver more colors with int hsl colors than with int rgb colors.

Comment: @elveti because of rounding. Of course. Issue is only that I have to round for CSS.

Comment: @Joschi How can hsl cover more colors than rgb? If you only look at the potential outputs of the functions `hsl(360,100,100)` and `rgb(255,255,255)`, then the amount of values you can express is much larger for rgb.

Comment: BTW rgb (at 8 bits) has `256^3`, but please try not to assume 8bit values, and BTW in hsl, all values with S=0 or L=0 describe the same colour.

Comment: PS: do not worry, we cannot see more then 3 millions of colour, for sure not on most computer screens.

Comment: @OleSpaarmann Oops! I mixed it up, sorry. Using int rgb and hsl gives you more css colors in rgb space for sure.

Comment: @OleSpaarmann for me it works with decimals in HSL https://jsfiddle.net/n2azqx9f/1/ Does it not work for you?

Comment: @elveti I have no idea why it did not work for me. It does indeed work. Strange. Thanks for pointing it out again!

Answer (score 4):

Technically, `hsl` notation can be used with [`<number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number) and not only integer. This make the possible colors more than what you already calculated and can cover all the rgb ones

```js
$('.box').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

```css
.box {
 height:40px;
 margin:10px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(12deg,11%,51%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(11.9deg,10.9%,50.9%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(11.1deg,10.9%,50.5%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(11.1deg,10.1%,50.5%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(11.1deg,10.1%,50.1%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(11deg,10%,50%)"></div>
```

Note that the angle can be expressed using `rad` and `turn`. A uniteless value is by default considered a `deg`. If degree is bettwen `0` and `360`, turn is only between `0` and `1` and radians is between `0` and `PI (3.14)`<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/angle)</sup>

```js
$('.box').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

```css
.box {
 height:40px;
 margin:10px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(1.12rad,11%,51%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(1.125rad,10.9%,50.9%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(1.125rad,10.9%,50.5%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(1.13rad,10.1%,50.5%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(1.134rad,10.1%,50.1%)"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:hsl(1.132rad,10%,50%)"></div>
```